# Unable to compile package due to missing dependency

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.romin.upm.es/wiki/index.php?title=ROS%3ATutorials/ROS_Configuration), but after creating my workspace and creating my initial MYROBOT_description package, when I run catkin_make, I get this error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "robot_state_publisher" with any of the following names:

    robot_state_publisherConfig.cmake
    robot_state_publisher-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "robot_state_publisher" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "robot_state_publisher_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
  above files.  If "robot_state_publisher" provides a separate development
  package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  myrobot/myrobot_description/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

Obviously, it can't find the "robot_state_publisher" my *_description package depends on, but I'm not sure why. I followed all the steps and made sure to add these lines to my ~/.bash_aliases:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source ~/workspace/myrobot/devel/setup.bash
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm building with Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207901/unable-to-compile-package-due-to-missing-dependency/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zymo](https://answers.ros.org/users/169313/zymo/) on 2023-08-10**:
Have you solved the problem? I met the same one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out that tutorial was missing a few steps. Fortunately, a later section mentioned you have to add dependencies by running:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo
```

After that, catkin_make ran without error.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2015-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0